# When installing MinGW I found this problem

Tags: c++, codeblocks, mingw32

When installing MinGW I found this problem

[image: 1]

I could not find a solution

Comment: Forget about the plain MinGW, get MinGW-w64 from https://www.msys2.org/ or http://winlibs.com/

Comment: Or unless you desperately need gcc for some reason, visual studio is a much better environment for windows

Comment: Please don't post errors as images unless it's actually a visual error. This helps others to find this question (and it's answers) if they search for the text.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to download Stephen T. Lavavej's (he is lead Microsoft STL developer) distro of mingw from his website: https://nuwen.net/mingw.html
No boring installation, just unpack archive, set path and use.

Comment: Looks a bit outdated (GCC 9) compared to more mainstream MinGW-w64 distros. Curious what the advantages are, the site just says "I maintain my own distro because I demand complete control".

Comment: Quite handy distro, has bunch of libs integrated into it, like boost. And GCC 9 still  suitable for many tasks. Othrwise, I'd recommend to use VS2019 on Windows, but that's quite huge an not so easy to install for novice.

Comment: MSYS2, for example, also has boost and has been shipping GCC 10 for months.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

The standalone build of MinGW-w64 (available for Windows 32-bit and 64-bit) from http://winlibs.com/ has no installer, just extract and start using it.